# error in installation of php5-curl

Tags: php, curl, ubuntu-12.04

i am trying to install php5-curl using the command

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

but i am getting the following error

```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   The following extra packages will be installed:
   php5-common php5-fpm
   Suggested packages:
   php5-suhosin php-pear
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
   php5-common php5-curl php5-fpm
   0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 673 not upgraded.
   Need to get 0 B/4,919 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 10.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
   Selecting previously unselected package php5-common.
   (Reading database ... 144138 files and directories currently installed.)
   Unpacking php5-common (from .../php5-common_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb) ...
   Selecting previously unselected package php5-fpm.
   Unpacking php5-fpm (from .../php5-fpm_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package php5-curl.
   Unpacking php5-curl (from .../php5-curl_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb) ...
   Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
   Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Setting up php5-common (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11) ...
    Setting up php5-fpm (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11) ...
   update-rc.d: warning: php5-fpm stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB  
   Default-Stop values (none)
   Setting up php5-curl (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11) ...
```

when i try running script having php requirement it gives error as

```
   /usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

what is this error i tried uninstalling and installing php5-curl but he same error is coming everytime

Comment: Have you tried [pecl](http://pecl.php.net)?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the `php5-cli` package which includes the command line php interpreter.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Comment: getting this error --->PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    
PHP Warning:PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/imap.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    also for/intl.so,mcrypt.so and more